# Wordpress foreign language in .php

Tags: php, wordpress, translation, language-translation

I'm editing a site for someone, and they are using wordpress, which I really don't like, but hey, I didn't pick it.  I need to change some text on their page to Portuguese characters such as Ç or Ã.  I've read in a few places, that I need to change from ASCII to UTF-8, but I'm not sure where to do that, or how to do it across the whole site.  Am I changing a database to UTF-8, or each individual php file?  Hopefully somebody knows, thanks.

Thanks to the comments below, I have most of the site running correctly, but now I can't get the foreign characters in just certain spots, for example, anywhere I'm using code like this inside of a .php file.

```
$email_list = do_shortcode('[pl_modal title="Join our email list" label="<img class=\'\' title=\'Join our email list\' src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/email_icon.png\'  /><br /><span>INSCREVA-SE A NOSSA<br />LISTA DE E-MAILS</span>"][gravityform id=1 title=false][/pl_modal]');
```

The portugese in the above code, if I add non english characters, I get a constantly loading error.  More code, that does the same thing.

```
'<div class="graphicbuttons_cont">' .
                                '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={19}&daddr={20}" target="_blank">
                                    <img title="Get Store Directions" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/getdirection_icon.png"  /><br /><span>LOCALIZACOES <br><br /> </span>
                                </a>' .
                            '</div>' .
```

the LOCALIZACOES in above text, should have special characters, but it won't hold them.  I have changed everything to UTF8 that I can find.  But there is nothing inside this specific file that says utf8, should I add something?

Comment: Change the Wordpress' Database Query Engine to use a charset of `UTF-8`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php I think it's defined within `wp-config.php`

Comment: In my wp-config.php file, it's already set with the DB_CHARSET as utf8, but I still can't add non english characters.  If I do add them, that part of the site disappears.

Comment: Eh? Disappears? Like an PHP error? What does it say with Error Reports on?

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn on Error Reports, but it doesn't really disappear, it actually keeps a spinning circle (loading...), forever.

Comment: Edited question to reflect current problem.

Comment: Wrap the strings with special characters with `htmlspecialchars()` or `hmtlentities()` function and see if it loads correctly then after =]

Comment: Nope, same thing.  Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If I used something like this http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm what format would I type the characters in?  Can anybody give an example of that, I haven't gotten it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so, if you change everything to utf8, and on wordpress all of your html code is in php files, the way I've used to use special characters is this

thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm

for example

```
<span>LOCALIZA&CcedilOES  </span>
```

will output LOCALIZAÇOES

Thanks to everyone for the help, I guess I could have been clearer on the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your application needs to be UTF-8.

- Your MySQL string columns should be `utf8_unicode_ci`.
- You need to ensure that your MySQL connection charset is set to UTF-8. You can do this via the query `SET NAMES utf8` (run once after every connection) or you can modify your my.cnf file if you have access to it.
- Your web pages should be served with `<meta charset="utf-8">`
- You can check and validate what kind of input you're receiving by using the PHP function [mb_check_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php).
- There's also a PHP ini setting called [default-charset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset).

Answer (score 0):

This can be changed two ways depending on your theme file. In the header.php file this should be near the top:

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
```

You use to be able to change this in the wordpress backend under settings -> reading. I believe now you have to manually change this in the wp-config.php file:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Comment: This has already been done, thanks for the comment, I rephrased the question above, since I didn't do a good job explaining it at first.